# Add value to key only with condition for hashmap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

Is there any way I could add a value (or change a key's value) to a key only if a condition is met?

I mean, something like:

```
myHashMap.add(key, if(true){//add this value} else {//add a different value});
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: @user1803551 this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Oh, it does. It shows you all you need to do in order to achieve what you want. It's even way more detailed than the answers you got.

Comment: @user1803551 I found the answer given to me more useful.

Comment: Because it does the work for you. You don't need to read and learn the basic material, you just copy-paste ready code. What you will really find useful is going through all the tutorial and then you wouldn't ask many questions.

Comment: @user1803551 Actually I did learn something new today. The one if statement liner. And instantly applied it, didnt copy-paste. As you may have noticed, the one liner in the answer was pretty generic. Sooo :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered in the basic tutorial.

Comment: You will learn more by actually reading it instead of making others give it to you, especially when it comes to such basic concepts. the ternary if is also covered in the tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use `if-else`:

```
if (condition){
    myHashMap.put(key, value);
} else {
    myHashMap.put(key, otherValue);
}
```

If you insist on making it short use the *ternary operator* (see the Oracle [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html), *The Conditional Operators* part):

```
myHashMap.put(key, condition ? value : otherValue);
```

Comment: Thanks. The second solution was what I was looking for.

Comment: @hello_its_me Yes, it is working for you; but pretty much bad style. At least you should wrap that thing into a separate method. The point is not writing the **shortest** code possible; being a good programmer is about writing the most **readable** code. And it is about learning and understanding concepts ...

Comment: @hello_its_me as ghostcat mentioned, you should be wary of writing code that can never be read.

Comment: @GhostCat to me ternaries are much more readable than `if` statements in most cases

Answer (score 3):

Just to tack on to Reut's answer, if you're wanting to operate on a value already in the map, there's Map#compute as of Java 8:

```
Map<String, String> example = new HashMap<>();
//pretending we have values...
example.compute("My Key", (key, oldValue) -> oldValue == null ? "New" : "Read");
```

Comment: Yes, I've been retrieving the older value and editing it. Not using this way tho, it looks more neat. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, you would have to do something like:

```
// Assuming a boolean value is returned
if (myHashMap.get(key)) {
    myHashMap.put(key, value);
} else {
    myHashMap.put(key, differentValue);
}
```

Comment: `add` is not a method of `Map`